# Have Tabulize ignore some lines and align the others

Tags: regex, vim, tabular

I would want Tabulize to ignore lines which do not have a particular character and then align/tabularize the lines ..

```
text1_temp = text_temp;
temporary_line;
text2    = text_temp;
```

In the end i would like the following :

```
text1_temp = text_temp;
temporary_line;
text2      = text_temp;
```

// The 2nd "=" is spaced/tabbed with relation to the first "="

If i run ":Tabularize /=" for the 3 lines together I get :

```
text1_temp     = text_temp;
temporary_line;
text2          = text_temp;
```

Where the two lines with "=" are aligned with respect to the length of the middle line

Any suggestions .. ?

PS: I edited the post possibly to explain the need better ..

Comment: Do you want to [remove white spaces behind `=`](https://regex101.com/r/kV0tB2/1) ?

Comment: As far as I can see, you want to un-tabularize those lines. Is this correct?
I think, you need another command then, like un-tabularize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how to do this with [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) directly. You might be able to use Christian Brabandt's [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin to filter out only lines with `=` using `:NRP` then running `:NRM`. This will give you a new buffer with only the lines with `=` so you can run `:tabularize/=/` and then save the the buffer (`:w`, `:x`, etc).

```
:g/=/NRP
:NRM
:tabularize/=/
:x
```

The easiest option is probably to use [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) which supports such behavior out of the box it seems. Example of using EasyAlign  (Using `ga` as EasyAlign's mapping you):

```
gaip=
```

Comment: The vim-easy-align part of the solution convinced me.

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple replace, like `:g/=/s/\t/ /g` ?

If that doesn't work, you can try this too: `:g/=/s/ \+= \+/ = /g`

**Explanation:**
The `:/g/=/s` will find all the lines that contain '=', and do the replacement for them.
So, `s/\t/ /g` will replace tabs with spaces. These two things combined will do what you need.